# Unable to X11 tunnel via ssh to Ubuntu 22.04.1 server

Tags: server, ssh, 22.04, x11-forwarding

I have a Ubuntu 22.04.1 server that was originally installed without a graphical environment. I added [XFce4 and Gnome](https://itsfoss.com/install-gui-ubuntu-server/) via apt. xauth is installed (and re-installed). When I ssh -X (or -Y) into it from both a Ubuntu live CD and a macOS wirth XQuartz installed (both clients work correctly when connecting to Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop, I get the following common error when running xterm:

```
Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

I've tried so may things I'm can't remember them all, but here is the sshd_config and some of my attempts:

```
jackie@server:~$ grep -v ^# /etc/ssh/sshd_config|grep -v ^$
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I've also tried with "X11UseLocalhost no" as suggested in [X11 forwarding broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96018/x11-forwarding-broken)

I've also connected with ssh -Y and run the following:

```
> ~/.Xauthority #that's not a prompt. it combines rm and touch into one command
xauth generate :0 . trusted
xauth add ${HOST}:0 . $(xxd -l 16 -p /dev/urandom)
xauth list
```

Which returns the following:

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".
server/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  39b005ef8b2b98461f80ebb165a36024
```

Which gives the usual display not set error, even on reconnecting

The [full ssh -Yvv log is available at this link](https://pastebin.com/dBnsRRwu).

Comment: Mabe you are running Wayland on the client?  Change to xorg at login (or the choice that doesn't have wayland).

Comment: Main client is macOS Running XQuartz, which only speaks X11. (Ubuntu desktop client was done from a live USB boot as a test.)

Comment: Did you ever run xhost on the client side?  Please add the output of xhost to your question to confirm your access to the X server.

Comment: "xhost +" on the clients was one thing I forgot to mentions: "access control disabled, clients can connect from any host", but that shouldn't matter on an ssh connection, as that's for the older X11 protocol. (It's not over a secure network, so I only did that to test on the live USB.) As I would expect, it produces the same error as w/o "xhost +" being run.

These days, you should never need to run xhost unless working with an ancient setup. (I'm enough of an old fart that I had to do that for X connections once upon a time in the last millenium.)

Answer (score 1):

I gave up, got the shotgun, and reinstalled as a Ubuntu desktop, since it wasn't a full production box. (I used server for netplan, which I can edit to avoid NetworkManager anyway, so it wasn't worth continuing to troubleshoot.)